# Is it possible to show an icon for a custom provider on Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I've set up a [custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) for my Firebase project where I use `signInWithCustomToken` to authenticate a user on Firebase.

If a user authenticates with a built-in Firebase provider like Google, Google's icon shows up under the "Providers" column.

Can I show an icon for my custom provider?

[image: Users tab on Firebase console]

Comment: Where exactly, in the Firebase Console?

Comment: @AlexMamo The screenshot I provided is of the Authentication > Users page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to configure your own icon for user accounts created by a custom provider. It does sound reasonable though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it.